# Latex equation writing problem: equals appears as minus

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}
     X=456
\end{equation}
```

after compiling it is showed

> x-456

where the = symbol gone

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Otherwise, we will not be able to help.

Comment: It's probably just the pdf or dvi viewer.

Comment: The check whether it is just the viewer or not, trying zooming in or out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that its showing x-456?
I reproduced the output and here you go. [image]

I'm not sure what went wrong with your file. Maybe you can post your code and then we can take a look into it